# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error in Spring Boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, jwt

I am new to unit testing and I have to test my methods in spring boot.
I created application with Spring Security JWT Authentication + PostgreSQL – RestAPIs SpringBoot + Spring MVC + Spring JPA from [this link](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-authentication-postgresql-restapis-springboot-spring-mvc-spring-jpa?fbclid=IwAR29x1W_t-iHWnJqCucOV7QpYMHuRGIKRc0xEeYNXIQh7JQdNcquju0vC80)
then I created controller for users to edit update ect.
My users controller looks like this

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class Users {



    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @GetMapping(value = "/*")//can access with this root
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") //Only admin can view all users' details
    public List<User> AllUsers(){

        return this.userService.getAllUsers();
    }



    @GetMapping(value = "/{username}")//can access with this root
    public User GetOneUser(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username){

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String auth_name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username

        if(auth_name.equals(username)||this.userService.isAdmin(auth_name)){//admin and user can see the details
            return this.userService.getUser(username);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }



    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")//can access with this root
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") //Only admin can delete user
    public void DeleteUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){

        this.userService.deleteUser(id);
    }




    @PostMapping(value = "/{username}")//can access with this root
    public User EditUser(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username,@RequestBody SignUpForm user) {//only user can edit

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String auth_name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
      User upUser=null;
       if(auth_name.equals(username)){
            upUser=this.userService.updateUser(username,user);


        }
       return upUser;

    }


}
```

then I created UserService like this:

```
    @Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;


    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        // return topics;
        List<User> users=new ArrayList<>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(users::add);
        return users;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin(String username){

        boolean flag=false;
        if(this.userRepository.existsByUsername(username)){
            User user=this.userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
            Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
            if(user.getId().equals(adminRole.getId())){
                flag=true;
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }

    public User getUser(String username){


        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
    }



    public User updateUser(String username, SignUpForm user) {

        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(username)) {
            User ExistingUser=userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
            if(ExistingUser.getName()!=user.getName()){
                ExistingUser.setName(user.getName());
            }
            if(ExistingUser.getUsername()!=user.getUsername()){
                ExistingUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            }
            if(ExistingUser.getPassword()!=user.getPassword()){
                ExistingUser.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            }

            if(ExistingUser.getEmail()!=user.getEmail()){
                ExistingUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            }



            Set<String> Roles =user.getRole();
            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

            Roles.forEach(role -> {
                switch(role) {
                    case "admin":
                        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                        roles.add(adminRole);

                        break;
                    case "pm":
                        Role pmRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_PM)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                        roles.add(pmRole);

                        break;
                    default:
                        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                        roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });

            if(ExistingUser.getRoles()!=roles){
                ExistingUser.setRoles(roles);
            }


              userRepository.save(ExistingUser);

            }

          return userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).get();

        }






        public void deleteUser(Long id) {

        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

it works.

But then I created class for testing that tests getUser() method from UserService

```
    @WebMvcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {


    @MockBean
    UserRepository repository;

   @Autowired
   UserService userService;



    @Test
    public void getUserTest(){
        User user=this.userService.getUser("arife");

        assertThat(user).isNotNull();


}

}
```

But it gives me error that looks like this:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authRestAPIs': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1662)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    ... 65 more
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: You are using a web based test to test a service. That is obviously not going to work. `@WebMVcTest` is for testing controllers, not testing services.

Comment: Did you try annotating UserDetailsServiceImpl with @Service? I hope UserDetailsServiceImpl is an implementation of a bean that you have autowired in your code.

Comment: Yes I annotated UserDetailsServiceImpl with @Service

Answer (score 1):

Is pretty hard to follow up your problem if you don't add more details (log trace, code snapshots...)

But maybe you can find this pet project done by me (https://github.com/geeksusma/jwt-rest-controller)

Basically is a RestController which works with JWT.

I hope it could help

Answer (score 0):

Now I wrote like this

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {




    @MockBean
    UserService userService;




    @Test
    public void getUserTest(){
        assertThat(this.userService.getUser("arife")).isNotNull();
    }



}
```

and then I added new File application-test.properties

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
#PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

now it gives me error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual not to be null

    at springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.springbootjwtauthenticationpostgresql.model.UserServiceTest.getUserTest(UserServiceTest.java:59)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I think that is not connected to database